# What's the best way to ask people who forked my repository on GitHub to update their forks?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have some repositories on GitHub that others have forked, but I notice they do not keep their forks up-to-date.  For example, my [PrimerPooler](http://ssb22.user.srcf.net/pooler) software for helping researchers of genetic diseases etc is on GitHub at [ssb22/PrimerPooler](https://github.com/ssb22/PrimerPooler) and has been forked by a Shanghai researcher at [Wy2160640/PrimerPooler](https://github.com/Wy2160640/PrimerPooler) but the fork is old and lacks important bug-fixes I made upstream.  Of course I don't mind old versions being kept for historical interest, but I would like this person to be made aware that their fork needs to be updated before any production use, otherwise their lab might get inaccurate results.  I cannot file an issue against the fork, nor is it obvious how to create a pull-request **from** master **to** fork (it seems there's no such thing as a "reverse pull request"); is there anything else I can do, other than sleuthing around to try and find this person's email address and hope their spam filters accept my email?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but it would be a good idea to tag your versions in git. You mention the changes made and bugs fixed in each version on the web page, but there does not seem to be a clear way to use a particular numbered version without going through old commits and looking for the appropriate changes. It would also be helpful to specify the version being downloaded on your download page. This would make it easier for anyone using the software to track the version they use and update based on fixes you push.

Comment: Thanks @GoodDeeds I've added some tags now